# What steps should you take to harden your website against censorship?

Tags: security, disaster-recovery

I am thinking about making a website for conservative crowdsourcing. Since AWS has shown they will ban customers, who spent who knows how much time building a platform on their infrastructure, I am not going to use any big cloud provider:

- aws
- google
- azure

I was just going to start with a normal, old school, non-cloud host and write it to be as host-infrastructure independent as possible. The only other thing I think I might need is DOS protection like cloudflare.

Is there anything I am missing? I don't think your domain registrar can be cancelled so I think it's safe to buy that from whoever is cheapest.

Comment: Tying the way your site works to any particular cloud infrastructure is a bad idea anyway.  You want to be able to move your site to a different provider they offer a better value.

Comment: It is probably important to take care that your domain registrar is non partisan (It seems thepiratebay is registered through EasyDNS and - https://kb.easydns.com/knowledge/easydns-official-takedown-policy/ - may be of interest), and it would be a good idea to design the storage (especially database) so that it is replicated among multiple back-ends - at which point you may actually want the site to be distributed.    Run conservative TTLs on your DNS.